# datatype mismatch in criteria expression vb2010 edit button

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting the error

> datatype mismatch in criteria expression vb.net edit button

when I click the edit button on my vb2010 project. Adding and search button works fine but not on edit button. 
Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub BtnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnEdit.Click
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=D:\pcInventory.accdb"
    myConnection = New OleDbConnection

    OpenStr = "Has Open Office"
    If TbPCnum.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select data.")
    Else

        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "update [pctable] set [Person Incharge] = '" & TbPI.Text & "', [DeptSection] = '" & TbDS.Text & "', [Workgroup] = '" & TbWG.Text & "', [Network ID] = '" & TbNI.Text & "', [OS] = '" & TbOS.Text & "', [Processor] = '" & TbProcessor.Text & "', [MOBO] = '" & TbMB.Text & "', [Memory] = '" & TbRAM.Text & "', [HDD] = '" & TbHDD.Text & "', [Product Key] = '" & TbKey.Text & "', [MS Office] = '" & CbMS.SelectedValue & "', [Open Office] = '" & tbOO.Text & "', [Anti Virus] = '" & TbAV.Text & "', [Monitor] = '" & TbMonitor.Text & "', [Email Address] = '" & TbEadd.Text & "', [Date Purchased] = '" & TbDP.Text & "', [Machine Type] = '" & comboMT.SelectedValue & "', [Remarks] = '" & TbRM.Text & "', [Password] = '" & TbPW.Text & "'     Where [PCNumber] = '" & TbPCnum.Text & "'"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            TbPCnum.Clear()
            TbPI.Clear()
            TbDS.Clear()
            TbWG.Clear()
            TbNI.Clear()
            TbOS.Clear()
            TbProcessor.Clear()
            TbMB.Clear()
            TbRAM.Clear()
            TbHDD.Clear()
            TbKey.Clear()
            tbOO.Clear()
            TbAV.Clear()
            TbMonitor.Clear()
            TbEadd.Clear()
            TbDP.Clear()
            TbRM.Clear()
            TbPW.Clear()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it may be your query string. You sending a string/text instead of an int/number for example.

check through it and make sure that the database column type matches the data you sending through with the query.

Remove the single quotation marks if you sending int/numeric values.

Comment: i hve another problem. is a way where i can extract a specific column form my database? for eg. I only want to export all my email addresses from my e-add  column on excel. is there any way to do that sir?

Comment: Nice. You should mark answers as correct so that others know what helped. To answer your other question, yes it can be done.